# I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException on Jenkisn while calling method from groovy script

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to call a method of the groovy script from Jenkins pipeline script and in that, I am getting 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getBuildsByDomain() on null object.

below is my Jenkins script

```
        pipeline{
          agent any
          environment{
              def EARLIESTDATE = '0'
              def LATESTDATE = '0'
            }
          parameters{
              string(defaultValue: "", description: 'Mention the Jenkins Directory. Like Dev/testforlder or DEV', name: 'JENKINS_DIRECTORY')
              string(defaultValue: "0", description: 'Enter the earliest date. Format: MM/dd/yyyy', name: 'EARLIEST_DATE')
              string(defaultValue: "0", description: 'Enter the earliest date. Format: MM/dd/yyyy', name: 'LATEST_DATE')
            }
            stages{
              stage("Getting Build Details"){
                steps{
                  script{
                    def rootDir = pwd()
                    echo "LOG-->INFO-->Current Working Directory : ${rootDir}"
                    echo "LOG-->INFO-->JENKINS DIRECTORY : ${params.JENKINS_DIRECTORY}"
                    echo "LOG-->INFO-->EARLIEST DATE : ${params.EARLIEST_DATE}"
                    echo "LOG-->INFO-->LATEST DATE : ${params.LATEST_DATE}"
                    def  FILES_LIST = sh (script: "ls   '${rootDir}'", returnStdout: true).trim()
                    //DEBUG
                    echo "FILES_LIST : ${FILES_LIST}"

                    def buildDetails = load "${rootDir}/getJobDetails.groovy"
                    echo "Script: ${buildDetails}"
                    buildDetails.getBuildsByDomain(params.JENKINS_DIRECTORY, params.EARLIEST_DATE, params.LATEST_DATE)
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            post{
              always {
                cleanWs()
              }
            }
        }
```

and the groovy script /getJobDetails.groovy

```
        import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder
        import jenkins.model.Jenkins
        import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
        import groovy.time.TimeCategory

        /*test=''
        getBuildsByDomain('DEV',test,test)*/

        def getBuildsByDomain(JENKINSDIR,EARLIEST_DATE, LATEST_DATE){
            def buildsByDomain = new Dictionary()

            def jenkinsDir = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(JENKINSDIR)
            echo "LOG-->INFO-->Directory to Check: ${jenkinsDir.getFullName()}"
            def folderObj = getFolders(jenkinsDir)
            //println "Folders to Check: ${folderObj}"

            folderObj.each{ folder ->
                //println "Folder: ${folder.name}"
                def jobObj = getJobs(folder)
                def totatBuilds = []
                //println "Job List: ${jobObj}"
                jobObj.each{job ->
                    def builds = []
                    builds = processJob(job,EARLIEST_DATE, LATEST_DATE)
                    totatBuilds = [totatBuilds, builds].flatten().findAll{it}
                    //println builds
                }
            buildsByDomain.put(folder.name,totatBuilds.size())
            //println "Total Builds: ${totatBuilds}"
            //println "Total Builds Count: ${buildCount = totatBuilds.size()}"
            }
            echo "LOG-->INFO-->Build Details By Domain: ${buildsByDomain}"
            //return buildsByDomain
        }

        def processJob(Item job,EARLIEST_DATE, LATEST_DATE){
            Date earliestDate = EARLIEST_DATE != '0' ? Date.parse('MM/dd/yyyy',EARLIEST_DATE): new Date() -7
            Date latestDate = LATEST_DATE != '0' ? Date.parse('MM/dd/yyyy', LATEST_DATE) : new Date()
            def buildnum = []
            if(job.getLastBuild() != null){
                //println job.name
                job.builds.each{
                    if (it.getTime().compareTo(earliestDate) == 1 && it.getTime().compareTo(latestDate) == -1 ){
                        buildnum.add(it.displayName[1..-1])
                    }
                }
                return buildnum
            }
        }

        def getJobs(Item folder){
            def jobs = []
            folder.getItems().each{
                if(it instanceof com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.AbstractFolder){
                    getJobs(it)
                }else{
                    jobs.add(it)
                }
            }
          return jobs
        }

        def getFolders(Item directory){
            def folders = []
            directory.getItems().each{
                if(it instanceof com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder){
                    folders.add(it)
                }
            }
            return folders
        }


        class Dictionary{
            def key
            def value
            def dict = [:]
            // Empty No-arg constructor. Required for the overloaded constructor below
            Dictionary() {}

            // A two-arg constructor to facilitate an entry to be added during instantiation
            Dictionary(key, value) {
            put(key,value)
            }

            // Method to validate the key, value inputs for not-null
            def validate(key, value){
                if(key==null)
                    throw new RuntimeException("groovy-log: Null key is not permitted")
                if(value==null)
                    throw new RuntimeException("groovy-log: Null value is not permitted")
            }

            // Actual method to store the key-value pairs.
            // Exception message printed if any of them is null.
            def put(key, value) {
                try {
                    validate(key,value)
                    this.dict[key]=value
                    printInfo()
                } catch(Exception exception) {
                    println "  #### ERROR #### --> " + exception.getMessage()
                    println " "
                }
            }

            // Overridden toString() to have a meaningful display
            String toString() {
                "Builds Count By Domain : ${dict}"
            }
        }
```

while runing it I with parameter I am getting below console output

```
            Commit message: "10.02"
            [Pipeline] }
            [Pipeline] // stage
            [Pipeline] withEnv
            [Pipeline] {
            [Pipeline] withEnv
            [Pipeline] {
            [Pipeline] stage
            [Pipeline] { (Getting Build Details)
            [Pipeline] script
            [Pipeline] {
            [Pipeline] pwd
            [Pipeline] echo
            LOG-->INFO-->Current Working Directory : /home/jenkins_agent/jenkins/workspace/Internal Jobs/JenkinsTools/Get_Jenkins_Metrics
            [Pipeline] echo
            LOG-->INFO-->JENKINS DIRECTORY : Dev
            [Pipeline] echo
            LOG-->INFO-->EARLIEST DATE : 0
            [Pipeline] echo
            LOG-->INFO-->LATEST DATE : 0
            [Pipeline] sh
             > git rev-list --no-walk 05d56d2022241f4c883709efb315a41a3d7fd330 # timeout=10
            + ls '/home/jenkins_agent/jenkins/workspace/Internal Jobs/JenkinsTools/Get_Jenkins_Metrics'
            [Pipeline] echo
            FILES_LIST : Achived
            getJobDetails.groovy
            main.jf
            [Pipeline] load
            [Pipeline] { (/home/jenkins_agent/jenkins/workspace/Internal Jobs/JenkinsTools/Get_Jenkins_Metrics/getJobDetails.groovy)
            [Pipeline] }
            [Pipeline] // load
            [Pipeline] echo
            Script: null
            [Pipeline] }
            [Pipeline] // script
            [Pipeline] }
            [Pipeline] // stage
            [Pipeline] stage
            [Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
            [Pipeline] cleanWs
            [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
            [WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
            [WS-CLEANUP] done
            [Pipeline] }
            [Pipeline] // stage
            [Pipeline] }
            [Pipeline] // withEnv
            [Pipeline] }
            [Pipeline] // withEnv
            [Pipeline] }
            [Pipeline] // node
            [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
            java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getBuildsByDomain() on null object
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
                at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
                at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:160)
                at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
                at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:27)
                at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
                at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
                at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
                at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor210.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
                at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:76)
                at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
                at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor469.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
                at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
                at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
                at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
                at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
                at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:237)
                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:182)
                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
                at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
                at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
            Finished: FAILURE
```

I am not bale to figure out what mistake i am doing. Please help me out to debug this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only place where you call `getBuildsByDomain`

```
buildDetails.getBuildsByDomain(params.JENKINS_DIRECTORY...
```

Means that `buildDetails` is null

You are getting `buildDetails` by loading `getJobDetails.groovy`

But `getJobDetails.groovy` script returns nothing.

Normally you should end it with `return this`

Comment: Adding ''' return this''' at the end works. But it seems the object buildsByDomain is not working I mean in the script console the object is giving required value but on the pipeline is not giving anything.

Comment: That's  another question )

Answer (score 0):

As for me the error is pretty clear explained.
You have NPE because "buildDetails" is null. "buildDetails" is the result of loading "${rootDir}/getJobDetails.groovy".
So I would start with checking ability to load this file for Jenkins. Existence, permissions etc.

Comment: Yes, the groovy file its self is not loading. However, I have validated the exact code inside groovy script on the Jenkins script console it was working there